# How to regurlarly update an output without closing it with Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know if it's possible to update an output (data, graphic) obtained with a Python script without closing this output ?

For example, let's say, I want to scrape some stock exchange to follow the fluctuation in real time. I scrape those data and it show me, for example in an excel file, or a graphic, those data in real time, regurlarly updated.

But it would be tedious if the output file would close ar each update. So I wonder if it's possible to do this in a way where the output will be showing the evolution of the data, updated in real time, without closing it ? It could b an excel file, or a plotly graph, I don't know, I just want to know if there any way to do this kind of task with Python ?

Comment: Why would that be tedious? You have a computer to do it for you.

Comment: If it close and re open each time the script update the output, it could be tedious because if I want the script top update, let's say, every 3 seconds, it would be illegible isn't it ? :)

Comment: Probably you should show some code to demonstrate the problem. The difference between closing the file and not closing the file should be a one-line difference in the code at most.

Comment: I haven't any code for now, I just want some informations !